# Find radius of split circle from arc length

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

A circle is divided by a line, which creates an arc (shown in *red*). I need to find the radius (**r**) of the circle, given the following:

- **Θ** - angle is unknown
- **M** - arc length is known
- circle center is known
- line parameters are known

I have managed to solve this iteratively, but I'm hoping that there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: The word "bisection" usually refers to being split in exactly half.

Comment: @Arthur thanks, I updated the question. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ be the distance from the center of the circle to the line (how you calculate this depends on how exactly your line is expressed). I am assuming that $c<r$. We have $M = r\Theta$ (if $\Theta$ is in radians), and some simple trigonometry shows us that $\cos \frac{\Theta}2 = \frac{c}r$. Putting these two equations together you get
$$
\cos\frac{M}{2r} = \frac cr
$$
which isn't really solvable for $r$ analytically. But any decent computer or calculator can give you the answer to a reasonable number of decimal places.